# How to add existing record instead of creating a new one with nested form and has_many :through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms

I have 3 models. There they are:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :client_users
  has_many :client_users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_users, allow_destroy: true
end

class ClientUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user, autosave: false

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients, through: :client_users
  has_many :client_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_users
end
```

When I creates a new client I have nested form for users. 
**The goal is**: create a new user if it doesn't exist and append if it already exist.
User model has unique email.

Which is the best way to do it?